# Validating Credit Card Inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm working on form validation in jQuery.  The form is working fine when just trying to validate the name, email and a check to ensure one activity is selected.  If a user selects credit card for payment I must run a validation on the cc number, zip code and cvv.  I tried to refactor the code and I think my logic is off somewhere as when I submit the form with no data, the only error message is on the CC digits and the form submits, when it should be prevented (via preventDefault).  No errors in console, so I know my logic must be messed up somewhere.  Any takers?

```
var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;


// Name can't be blank
function validateName(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var error_name = true
    if (name === ''){
        $(".error_name").show();
        console.log('name cant be empty');
    } else {
        error_name = false;
    }
    return error_name

}
// Email must be valid
function validateEmail(){
    var email = $('#mail').val();
    var error_mail = true;
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);
    error_email = pattern.test(email);
    if (!error_email){
        $(".error_email").show();
        error_email = true;
    } else {
        error_email = false;
    }
    return error_email
}
// One Activity Must Be Selected
function validateActivities(){
    var totalActivities = $('.activities input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    var error_activity = true;
    if (totalActivities < 1) {
        $(".error_activities").show();
    } else {
        error_activity = false;
    }
    return error_activity
}

// Validate the Credit Card Number --Make sure is between 13 to 16 digit number
function validateCC(){
    var cc = $("#cc-num").val();
    var errorCC = true;
    errorCC = intRegex.test(cc);
    if ((!errorCC) || ((cc.length < 13) || (cc.length > 16))){
        $(".error_cc").show();
        errorCC = true;
    } else {
        errorCC = false;
    }
    return errorCC
}

function validateZip(){
    var zip = $("#zip").val();
    var errorZip = true;
    errorZip = intRegex.text(zip);
    if ((!errorZip)||(zip!= 5)){
        $(".error_zip").show();
        errorZip = true;
    } else {
        errorZip = false;
    }
    return errorZip
}

function validateCVV(){
    var cvv = $("#cvv").val().length;
    var errorCVV = true;
    errorCVV = intRegex.text(cvv);
    if ((!errorCVV)||(cvv!= 3)){
        $(".error_cvv").show();
        errorCVV = true;
    } else {
        errorCVV = false;
    }
    return errorCVV
}

//Check for Credit Card Issue -- Any problems with CC, Zip Code or CVV
function validateCredit(){
    var credit = $("#payment option[value='credit card']")
    errorCC = validateCC();
    errorZip = validateZip();
    errorCVV = validateCVV();
    isCreditIssue = false;
    if (credit.prop('selected', true)){
        if ((errorCC) || (errorZip) || (errorCVV)){
        isCreditIssue = true;
        console.log('credit issue');
        }
     }
    return isCreditIssue
}


// On Form Submission Validate Form
$("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
    error_name = validateName();
    error_email = validateEmail();
    error_activity = validateActivities();
    isCreditIssue = validateCredit();

    if ((error_name) || (error_email) || (error_activity) || (isCreditIssue)){
        event.preventDefault();
    }



});
```

Comment: what is this `#contact_submit button`? type `button` or type `submit`? have u put `console.log` to check if the checking is hit?

Comment: It's a button with type submit.  Everything seemed to be stopping submission (with errors) until I started checking for number validation on credit card stuff.  It's weird because it is not validating all of the other name, email inputs now either.  So not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: maybe attached a jsfiddle will be great? looking at the script, seem to be working fine

Comment: okay here you go https://jsfiddle.net/reoy96g7/   i hope this helps--first time I've actually used jfiddle

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: intRegex is not defined`, what is `intRegex`? you might forgot to attach the js that needed?

Comment: shoot forgot to include this  var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;

Comment: so i guess that solve ur issue?

Comment: That regex `/[0-9 -()+]+$/` doesn't seem right: it's checking that the input *ends* with at least one of those characters, but it would allow other characters at the beginning, e.g., `"abcdabcdabcd1234"` would pass.

Comment: sorry i mean i forgot to include in jfiddle--it is declared as global var at top of my js code

Comment: is this a typo or ? `intRegex.text`, it should `intRegex.test` and i tested, seem to working fine, I did not test for the cc validation accuracy though, is that solve your issue?

Comment: yep---good catch!  that fixes some issues---the only problem is the form is still submitting when there are errors

Comment: what errors that you mention? related to the question?

Comment: *"the only problem is the form is still submitting when there are errors"* - Do you mean that the validation code is failing to pick up on invalid values and the submit goes ahead? If so, refer to my previous comment about the regex being wrong.

Comment: yes, so i just submit the form with no data it tries to submit when it should be stopping because of errors--as i have tried to do with preventDefault on submit

Comment: does that look right?  var intRegex = /[0-9]$/;    regex is like my kryptonite

Comment: plus because of this--- if ((error_name) || (error_email) || (error_activity) || (isCreditIssue)){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: i don't know why it is still submitting--because the first three should be true

Comment: submit with no data but still pass? https://jsfiddle.net/reoy96g7/2/ the jsfiddle is working fine, + @nnnnnn  regex

Comment: well what do you know it is working----thanks guys!  i guess i was the regex all along @nnnnnn   have a good one

Comment: The regex should start with `^` and end with `$` to match the beginnning and end of the input, in your case `/^[0-9]+$/`, otherwise you're just matching somewhere within the input and not the whole input.

Comment: awesome thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: @nnnnnn should put it as answer and mark it, as an appreciation for helping you on the question

Comment: @nnnnn certainly happy to help out if you want to do that